# FabricJS: How to reposition an event listener?

Tags: events, listener, move, fabricjs

I've got a problem with event listeners in FabricJS. 
Basically I am creating child-circles around a root-circles and depending on the amount of child-circles their position changes, so they are positioned equally around the root. This approach forces me to reposition a child-circle AFTER it has been created and here comes the point:

**When I put an event listener on a child, the listener seems to track only the position at the time of the creation of a particular object, not the final/current position.**

It is also the same problem when I put the listener on the whole canvas object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.ChildCircles.length; i++)
{

    this.ChildCircles[i].set({  left:   this.CenterX + Distance * Math.cos(i * StepDegrees * Math.PI / 180), 
                                    top:    this.CenterY + Distance * Math.sin(i * StepDegrees * Math.PI / 180)
                            });                             

}
```

This is how I reposition the objects. For the event listener I use the regular on()-function. Please help!

Comment: Make working fiddle and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Sry, for not answering. I actually figured out that the "canvas" approach wasn't right for m, so I switched to SVG. Since I want to interact with the circles (events => zoom in/out etc.) I use a SVG framework called [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/). It solves the problem above because the "listener" (it becomes a DOM event I guess) sticks to the object instead of beeing calculated each time by the framework.